# Enable "Generate comments" in New Java Class Wizard per default

Tags: eclipse

In our company we have configured a custom class header.
When I enable "Generate comments" in the "New Java Class"-Wizard they are added automatically.

Is there a way to enable this checkbox per default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Neon.1. It tells you how to do just that right in the **New Class** wizard (the **Code Templates** preference page).

Answer (score 0):

You can configure this in the Preferences in 'Java > Code Style > Code Templates'.

Select the 'Automatically add comments for new methods and types' check box at the bottom of the page.